# Extract columns using a character variable in both data frames and data tables

Tags: r, data.table

Data frames and data.tables behave differently when selecting columns using a variable with column names.
**Is there a single expression that will work for both types of data structures?**
Why do I care?
I have some user-defined functions originally written for data frames, and would like them to work for both frames and tables.

Here is an example.
Make a data frame and a data.table.

```
> fr <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 1)                                                                     
> tb <- data.table::data.table(a = 1, b = 1)
```

Here is a vector with a column name.

```
> v <- 'a'
```

It can be used to extract a column from the data frame like this:

```
> fr[, v]                                                                                            
[1] 1
```

But data.tables require something else.

```
> tb[, v]                                                                                            
Error in `[.data.table`(tb, , v) :                                                                   
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'v' is not found. Perhaps you 
intended DT[, ..v]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.            

> tb[, ..v]                                                                                          
   a                                                                                                 
1: 1                                                                                                 

> tb[, v, with = FALSE]                                                                              
   a                                                                                                 
1: 1
```

Neither of these options that work with data tables will work with data frames.

```
> fr[, ..v]                                                                                          
Error in `[.data.frame`(fr, , ..v) : object '..v' not found      

> fr[, v, with = FALSE]                                                                              
Error in `[.data.frame`(fr, , v, with = FALSE) :                                                     
  unused argument (with = FALSE)
```

Is there an approach that works for both data frames and data.tables?

I know I can use this list-style indexing for both:

```
> fr[[v]]                                                                                            
[1] 1                                                                                                

> tb[[v]]                                                                                            
[1] 1
```

But that only works if I don't need to include a row index as well.

From [FAQ 1.5](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#j-num) I would think I could change an option to get the desired behavior.
This could be a solution, but I don't see what I would expect.

```
> options(datatable.WhenJisSymbolThenCallingScope=TRUE)                                              

> options()$datatable.WhenJisSymbolThenCallingScope                                                  
[1] TRUE               
                                                                              
> tb[, v]                                                                                            
Error in `[.data.table`(tb, , v) :                                                                   
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'v' is not found. Perhaps you 
intended DT[, ..v]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.
```

Am I confused?

```
> packageVersion('data.table')                                                                       
[1] ‘1.14.2’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
fr <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 1)                                                                     
tb <- data.table::data.table(a = 1, b = 1)      

v<-'a'

subset(fr, , get(v))
#>   a
#> 1 1

subset(tb, , get(v))
#>    a
#> 1: 1
```

Comment: Note that data.table library defines `data.table:::subset.data.table()` so it is a data.table method.

Comment: This works, thank you! And I can include a logical/relational row index.

Answer (score 1):

`.subset2` accepts a string:

```r
.subset2(tb, v)
.subset2(fr, v)
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of this function. This approach will work if there is no need for a row index. I think it is equivalent to the `[[v]]` I used in my question. Good to know, but it seems `subset()` is a more flexible option because of the row index capability.

Answer (score 0):

The `[[ ]]` approach actually might be the best solution, because a row index can be added to the right, and unlike `subset()`, this approach can be used for assignment too.

```
> fr <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 1) 
> 
> fr <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 1:10) 
> v <- 'a'
> fr[[v]][1]
[1] 1
> fr[[v]][1] <- 100
> fr
     a  b
1  100  1
2    2  2
3    3  3
...
> 
> tb <- data.table::data.table(a = 1:10, b = 1:10) 
> tb[[v]][1]
[1] 1
> tb[[v]][1] <- 100
> tb
      a  b
 1: 100  1
 2:   2  2
 3:   3  3
...
```